# convertapi pdf to image: specify page range

Tags: pdf, range, png, convertapi

I need a png thumbnail of various document types, just the first page, in order to have a quick preview.  For a docx document, it is possible to specify page range.  But for a pdf file, there is no page range parameter, so it converts all the pages, with potentially a huge cost.   Am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you tried PDF to Thumbnail Rest API?  https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-thumbnail It has a page range and very fast.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that seems to be doing what I need, thanks.   Still it might be useful and consistent to have a range argument in pdf to image.

Comment: It could be done using pdf-split and pdf-image by chaining these actions.